# How to URL dispath for tailing slash on Pyramid

Tags: pyramid

I want to ignoring lasted `/` for a path. It means `/page` and `/page/` are same route URL.

My route config is:

```
config.add_route('page', '/page')
```

I'm using `pyramid 1.8.2` and `Python3.5.2`.

Please let me know solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this situation is in the docs, [Redirecting to Slash-Appended Routes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#redirecting-to-slash-appended-routes).